# Fantasy manhwa where the empress is a witch and killed by her brother then reborn as a slave

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I was scrolling through the group page and I saw someone wants to know the title of this. I forgot the name.

The heroine has silver hair (a slave) and the hero has black hair (an emperor). The story is revived, meaning the heroine was an empress and a powerful witch, and then she dies at the hands of her little brother, whom she loved, and is revived as a slave in another kingdom, and there it is.  She meets the emperor, whom she knew when he was young, and he suspects that it is her because she has the same appearance.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: If it's on the group page, will you know if it's the answer?